# How does a member initialization list work with char pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, initializer-list, string-literals, char-pointer

I understand that a member initialzation list can be used to initialize objects and variables that have a known size.

However, how does a member initialization list actually work with pointers, in particular `const char*` pointers, as in `MyClass` below? Will it simply point to the memory location of the `const char*` which I pass in?

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass(const char* str): _str(str)
    {
    }

  private:
    const char* _str;
};
```

Comment: *It will simply point to the memory location of the const char* which I pass?* Yep.  What behavior are you trying to get?  Do you want `Myclass` to have a copy of the passed in c-string?

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re referring to. The code you posted does not involve initializer lists. Did you mean class member initializers?

Comment: I think that `const char*` has a known size

Comment: @Engineer999 The both pointers str and _str will point to the same object.

Comment: If you want the text copied: 1) Allocate same or larger space as text pointed to by `str`; 2) Copy the text using `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will simply *initialize* `_str` with the *value* of `str` - ie, make `_str` point to the same memory address that `str` is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that a member initialzation list can be used to initialize objects and variables that have a known size.

Member initialization lists can be used to initialize members and base sub objects. Those always have a known size.

> However, how does a member initialization list actually work with pointers

All pointers have a known size.

> Will it simply point to the memory location of the const char* which I pass in?

Yes. That's what a pointer value is.